# Create a product in Prestashop from database

Tags: mysql, database, prestashop

I'm trying to create a product in prestashop from the database. I have created the most simplest product in Prestashop (only name, price and category) with id_product x and I have looked for in the database what tables have that value in id_product, and create the same row with id_product x+1, but it doesn't show in Prestashop Panel. The tables I write are the following:

```
ps_category_product
ps_layered_price_index
ps_product
ps_product_lang
ps_product_shop
ps_specific_price
ps_stock_available
```

Any ideas what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

```
       ps_product_supplier
        ps_product_tag
        ps_feature_product
        ps_image
        ps_product_attachment
        ps_product_attribute
        ps_product_attribute_combination
        ps_product_attribute_image
        ps_product_attribute_shop
        ps_product_carrier
        ps_product_country_tax
        ps_product_download
        ps_product_group_reduction_cache
        ps_product_sale
        ps_product_tag
```

Regards

Comment: It doesn't work. I finally used the Prestashop API for c#: https://github.com/Bukimedia/PrestaSharp